# SugarCRM - Add field "opportunity age"

Tags: sugarcrm

I would like to add a field "opportunity age", which shows the opportunity's age in minutes / hours / days. Logic hooks appear not to be the right solution, as they are only executed when the opportunity is modified.

Any ideas?

Best,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process_record logic hook should be triggered on a dashlet or list view.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via Sugar Logic if you are using Pro or above with the following formula:

```
concat(multiply(daysUntil($date_entered),-1)," days")
```

See http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/02/16/howto-calculate-the-number-of-days-since-a-date/ for more info

Comment: I ended up writing my own logic hook, as I want to display the age on a minute / hour level. Now, the hook works fine for the editviews, etc. but does not trigger within the dashlets. It is defined as 'after_retrieve'. Does this not trigger with dashlets?